# Specifying output uri for a Disco mapreduce job

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, disco

I would like to have a completed Disco job write directly to mongodb. Is there an easy way to specify an output url for Disco to send its data to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct compatibility layer between Disco and MongoDB, although early work on such a layer is in progress. In the meantime, I would have your Disco job write to CSV or JSON (1 object per line), which you can easily import to MongoDB using `mongoimport`. See [the MongoDB wiki](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport) for more details.